# How can I check for MS15-011/15-014 (JASBUG)?

Tags: powershell, registrykey

I am trying to build a PowerShell script that would check machines for this vulnerability.  But I want to do the check at the registry level.  I do not trust the Add/Remove programs listing for KB3000483.  I need to know for sure that SMB and GPO are set correctly.  I need this because I am doing this check on many 100s of machines and who has time to check by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Systeminfo for see all hotfix installed 
for example when i use command systeminfo i get

```
Hotfix(s):                 255 Hotfix(s) Installed.
```

and a lot of information about windows like 'last boot !'
and for run this command in all your client in domain you can use gpo and set group policy run script at startup for all your clients,
another way for run command on all machine u want you can use "Invoke-Command"
syntax is very simple like :

```
$command = { Get-EventLog -log "Windows PowerShell" | where {$_.Message -like "*certificate*"} }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName S1, S2 -ScriptBlock $command
```

you can add [-Credential ] for authentication in all pcs 
another way you can use system center for run command in all your machines u control with system center
Regards

Comment: Ok, this is a good start however I need to know a little more about the specific registry keys that are updated by the KB3000483 (MS15-011/014) JASBUG patch.  Particularly the nature of the JASBUG rating a 10 on MS's scale, I think it would be possible for the right malware to make it look like the patch is installed even though it is not.

Comment: The specific registry keys I am curious about are smb version 1 and verson 2 settings and if mutual authentication and integrity are enabled and required.

Comment: i don't know which exactly update you want but in powershell you can use this command `wmic qfe list  full` and you can use `get-string` for get update you want i hope help to you dude

Answer (score 1):

You can query WMI to look into the Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering to see a list of all of the installed patches.  The code to find this particular patch is as follows:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Where HotFixID -eq KB3000483
```

Now, if you wanted to query a big group of computers, I'd use code like this:

```
'localhost','offline' | ForEach {

    try {$a=Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering  -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName $_ | Where HotFixID -eq KB3000483 | Select HotFixID,InstalledOn,@{Name='Status';Exp={'Installed'}},@{Name='SystemName';Exp={$_.CSName}} }
   catch{$a= [pscustomobject]@{HotFixID="NA";InstalledOn='NA';Status='Not Installed';SystemName=$_}}
 finally{[pscustomobject]@{HotFixID=$a.HotFixID;InstalledOn=$a.InstalledOn;Status=$a.Status;SystemName=$a.SystemName} }

   }
```

The results?

```
HotFixID                         InstalledOn                      Status                           SystemName                      
--------                         -----------                      ------                           ----------                      
KB3000483                        2/14/2015 12:00:00 AM            Installed                        BEHEMOTH                        
NA                               NA                               Not Installed
```

So, to run this on your whole environment, just substitute my 'localhost','offline', etc with a query like `Get-AdComputer -LdapFilter...` or read from a CSV or text file.

Now, if you're curious about the Try $a/ Catch $a lines, what we're doing here is using Try/Catch/Finally to try some code, if an error is encountered we use the catch block instead.  We are storing the examples of both in $a so that we can pull them out in the finally{} block to get some nice standardized output.  If we run into a system that doesn't have the patch, or that is offline, the Catch{} block gets executed instead.

Hope this gets you started!

Comment: You're way too caught up on these regkeys. Querying WMI with my method is the way to go, and I've given a turnkey solution for your environment.

Comment: Ok, I will take what you have given me but I will post back with the rest of the script that includes the keys.

Comment: Sounds good! To check for a remote registry keys, you can verify using test-path - computername $computer hklm:\pathtoregkey